# Android Build Tools 1.1.0 - Lint fails on Unknown issue id "ImproperProjectLevelStatement"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-lint

I upgraded an app from android gradle build tools 1.0.0 to 1.1.0. Lint fails now with:

LintError: Lint Failure
Unknown issue id "ImproperProjectLevelStatement"

Comment: It might be helpful to show the code which generates this error

Comment: Unfortunately, lint does not point to a specific line in code as this is a lint failure and not a lint warning/error. Full description:  Priority: 10 / 10
Category: Lint
Severity: Error
Explanation: Lint Failure.
This issue type represents a problem running lint itself. Examples include failure to find bytecode for source files (which means certain detectors could not be run), parsing errors in lint configuration files, etc.
These errors are not errors in your own code, but they are shown to make it clear that some checks were not completed.